# Резиновый текст

Tags: css, css3, шрифты, текст, масштабирование

Как создать [такой](https://youtu.be/CmcN0nwI16w) эффект с текстом

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно растягивать текст и в ширину, и в высоту, а так как соотношение сторон может меняться - то обычным font-size здесь не обойтись. 
Как вариант - сделать блок, который будет иметь ширину и высоту в зависимости от текста внутри (т.е. auto) и уже этот блок поместить в тот блок, который можно будет растягивать. А уже при изменении его высоты\ширины высчитывать коэффициент насколько она больше высоты\ширины блока с текстом и применять к блоку с текстом `transform: scaleX(coeffW)` для ширины и `transform: scaleY(coeffH)` для высоты

Получится вот такая функция, которую необходимо применять для блока каждый раз, когда нужно чтобы текст подстраивался:

```
function resize(block){
  block.css({
    'transform-origin': '0 0',
    'transform': 'scaleX(1) scaleY(1)'
  });
  var parent = block.parent(),
        block_width = block.outerWidth(),
        block_height = block.outerHeight(),
        parent_width = parent.width(),
        parent_height = parent.height(),
      coeffX = parent_width / block_width,
      coeffY = parent_height / block_height;

  block.css({
    'transform-origin': '0 0',
    'transform': 'scaleX('+coeffX+') scaleY('+coeffY+')'
  });  
}
```

Пример: https://jsfiddle.net/92avdxyv/1/

Comment: Спасибо большое! Попробую поколдовать. Я так понимаю, здесь одним css не получится обойтись? В любом случае нужно применять js?

Comment: И задача состоит не в том, что нужно будет растягивать этот блок, а в том, что в зависимости от разрешения окна этот блок с текстом будет сжиматься

Comment: то есть в ручную никто не будет его растягивать.

Comment: просто у меня размер сайта задан полностью в процентах и блоки без текста растягиваются как резина при изменении размеров окна, а вот с текстом такой махинации не происходит

Comment: Учитывая что блок с текстом должен менять значение transform относительно родительского элемента, вам в любом случае нужно будет высчитывать коэффициенты для scale. В css для этого могла бы подойти функция calc(), но она не может использовать значения других свойств (т.е. вычислять в transform на основе width). Хотя, может если покопаться - то можно найти способ, т.к. я не в курсе как вообще работает calc(), но даже на js как видите не заметно никаких "прыжков текста", хоть для точного вычисления коэффициентов и приходится сперва их присваивать 1, а потом уже менять на корректные.

Comment: Там в примере возможность вручную менять - просто для наглядности. Можете в css изменить ширину\высоту и посмотреть что при загрузке они автоматически применяются.

Comment: Понял. Спасибо за помощь! Буду пробовать.

Comment: Скажите, а как сделать, чтоб эта функция обрабатывала несколько блоков с разным текстом. Просто у меня подгоняется текст только в первом блоке, а остальной подтягиваются по значению первого

Comment: Ну вообще, в функцию передается блок который необходимо подогнать. В итоге на каждый блок который необходимо растягивать навесьте класс resizable а уже при загрузке страницы/изменении размера окна вызывайте для каждого блока с этим классом эту функцию

Comment: А вы мне можете пример показать на нескольких блоках. Я просто в js новичок.

Comment: не совсем понимаю, как это правильно прописать

Comment: На данный момент я скопировал функцию для каждого блока в html. в итоге получился огромный код. Знаю, что это не правильно. просто не понимаю как вызывать функцию из js файла для каждого блока

Comment: ну выглядеть должно примерно так:
`$('.resizable').each(fuction(){
   resize($(this));
})`
а её уже вставлять в `$(window).load()` или `$(window).resize()`

Comment: У меня возникла проблема. В html скрипт, который вы писали первый, работает хорошо, а вот в php не работает в IE 11

Comment: Что значит не работает в php в ие11? Это же JS код. При чем тут php?)

Comment: index файл изначально был html и все работало. но мне нужен был php, так как буду работать с БД. я в php файл все скопировал с html и начались сбои при загрузке

Comment: Ну тут еще бы неплохо знать что подразумевается под сбоями, что пишет сама консоль и одинаковый ли код генерирует php по сравнению с тем что в html

Comment: А возможно этот кот прописать на jequery? возможно будет с ним работать

Comment: Ну вообще-то, jquery это только библиотека JS и все что работает на обычном JS работает и на jQuery, но не наоборот. Да и я изначально с расчетом на jQuery писал. Просто от него ничего не нужно)

Comment: В общем сравнил код. В php файле почему-то добавляются лишние отступы в коде. и как раз между тегами skript стоит перенос на другую строку. а вот в хроме код правильный. полазил на форуме. говорят это проблема с кодировкой. у меня стоит utf-8. сайт англоязычный. чем можно заменить или исправить эту проблему, пока не пойму

Answer (score 0):

```js
//авто_подбор_текста_под_контейнер
//работает через jQuery
(function($) {
  $.fn.sizeText = function(kompressor, options) {
    var compressor = kompressor || 1,
      settings = $.extend({
        'minFontSize': Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY,
        'maxFontSize': Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY
      }, options);
    return this.each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      var resizer = function() {
        $this.css('font-size', Math.max(Math.min($this.width() / (compressor * 10), parseFloat(settings.maxFontSize)), parseFloat(settings.minFontSize)));
      };
      resizer();
      $(window).on('resize.sizetext orientationchange.sizetext', resizer);
    });
  };
})(jQuery);
//вставить_в_контейнер(body,div куда нужно) id="sizeText"
//в функцию нужный размер текста --> sizeText(1)
//автоматически размер текста будет изменяться
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#sizeText").sizeText(1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body id="sizeText">

  <div>
    HTML
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Ставил на сайт лет 6 назад, резиновый сайт - резиновый текст вот ссылка http://xn--c1aea1as8b9aw.xn--p1ai/ . В функции sizeText(7) число 7 соответствует 1em(100%) , размер в браузере по умолчанию. Работает прекрасно.

Comment: Спасибо! попробую..